# Could not open the dk file

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I dont know what I have done, but it is over a month now that I can not open my virtual machine, I'm using a MacBookPro with Fusion 2.0.6. I recently upgraded my system to Snow Leopard. but it was working fine. Now I get a message that says" File not found: Windox XP. vmdk.

I went to all my backups and when I unpack the files in the virtual machine, there is not such a file. the only file that I can see that may contents the data is the .vmem file that show to have 1.2 GB of data.

I have tryed and tryed to contact VMware support but it has become an impossible task, If theres someone that could give me some ideas on how to recover my virtual machine????

Answer (score 0):

the vmdk file is the hard disk for your vm. if it is missing, there is nothing that can be done.

to verify if it is there, find your virtual machine file. right click on it, and show package contents. find the .vmx file and open it in a text editor. do a search for vmdk, and you may see something like

```
scsi0:0.fileName = "Windows 7.vmdk"
```

that's the name of your virtual machine disk. try a spotlight search to see if you moved it somewhere else. another option is to check to see if there are any really large files in your vm package contents. if there are a series of 2gb files or one big (>5gb) file, those may be vmdk files that have been renamed or corrupted in some way.

the reason it isn't in your backups is because time machine does not back up vmdk files. see the vmware forums for [fusion backup strategies](http://communities.vmware.com/message/826453).